# Is polling in jQuery expensive, and are there alternatives?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have several users accessing my page at the same time, with each client polling (using 
setInverval) another php script that reads a value from a database and prints it.

```
setInterval( "printData();", 300 );
```

I'm relatively new to jQuery and javascript, and I'm a bit skeptical of the viability of constantly running this php script and constantly making database queries.

Can someone calm my nerves or provide an alternative to my current method?

Comment: question, when does the value in the database change? You have 3 options: polling, long-poll (aka hidden frame) or websockets. [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) is a js/.NET library that uses websockets with a fallback to long-polling or normal polling, depending on the browsers support. Maybe you can use this in PHP too.

Comment: long-polling/websockets are only usefull if you have control when the value in the database changes and you can arrange an event mechanism to notify the clients currently connected. So you can push the changed data to the client.

Comment: You can find jQuery examples of the 3 techniques I've mentioned [here](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery)

Comment: @WouterH - yes to long-polling, though presumably SignalR wouldn't be of any use in a PHP application?

Comment: That's why I started my last sentence with 'Maybe' :). Anyway he could look at SignalR's javascript implementation to see how they do the fallback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are updating it every 0.3 seconds - that's over 3 times a second. Way too much. Depending on how smooth it needs to be, update it at most every 5 seconds (`5000`) instead.

Also, just to make it a little faster, just drop the quotes and parentheses:

```
setInterval(printData,5000);
```

Comment: I'd like the data to be updated more than five times a second. Is there a way that I can update the data for all my clients that is triggered by a change in the database as opposed to polling it and printing the value?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `setInterval` is probably not the best option here. Better to use `setTimeout` recursively in the success handler of your AJAX call.

Comment: you are looking for long-polling. Which in essence does this: the client sends a HTTP request, but the server (PHP script) doesn't answer until there is a data-change. The client receives this change immediatly. In case the HTTP server closes the long-polling connection, due to a timeout, the client immediatly repeats the HTTP request to recreate the connection.